# Accessing instance variable from anom. function in coffee script

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to access @cols from anom function, it is coming as undefined (at second last line) even though it is defined.

```
csv = require 'csv'

class Inventory

    constructor: (@file) ->
        @cols = {}      

        #Read the file and push to cols
        csv().
        fromPath(@file,columns: true ).
        on 'data', (d,index)->
            #push to cols
            console.log @cols

inventory = new Inventory(__dirname + '/sample.csv')
```

Comment: What does 'anom function' stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fat arrow instead of the slim one.

```
(d, index)=>
```

Answer (score 2):

use => instead of -> so you can use @ and get a reference to the outer instance

```
csv = require 'csv'

class Inventory

    constructor: (@file) ->
        @cols = {}      

        #Read the file and push to cols
        csv().
        fromPath(@file,columns: true).
        on 'data', (d,index) =>
            #push to cols
            console.log @cols

inventory = new Inventory(__dirname + '/sample.csv')
```